# Merge of Questions

Tags: feature-request

Would it be instructive to merge questions?

For example, the cornucopia of these questions on "all but", with sterling answers, makes it toilsomely exacting and incommoding to compare and contrast:

●["to be all but X"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9323/to-be-all-but-x)
● ["all but one refused to do" means everyone do it or only one did it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64317/all-but-one-refused-to-do-means-everyone-do-it-or-only-one-did-it?lq=1)
● [Interpreting the meaning of 'but' as an implication for exclusion/inclusion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/interpreting-the-meaning-of-but-as-an-implication-for-exclusion-inclusion?lq=1)
● ["All but" idiom has two meanings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9967/all-but-idiom-has-two-meanings?rq=1)
● ["He all but [did something]"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33411/he-all-but-did-something)
● ["all but at most one" - What does it mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55869/all-but-at-most-one-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: It might be useful to have a tag for [all-but].

Answer (score 2):

This sort of duplication is the exact reason we close questions as duplicates if you can the answer you are looking for in the original set of answers.

The appropriate way to solve this problem is to not wait for all of the various flavors to appear and then merge them; the appropriate solution is to aggressively close similar questions as duplicates. In rare circumstances this could also entail editing the original question if it happens to be too narrow.

As for what to do about the *current* situation now that we failed in closing the duplicates, I vote to leave them be. I don't see anything specific to be gained in trying to edit, merge or close them now.

Comment: @TimLymington: I don't mind the help but you accidentally changed the meaning of a sentence so I rolled back the edit.

Comment: If you really meant 'close them after not waiting', I don't think I understand; please make it clear enough for those of us reading late at night.

Comment: "If you can the answer"?